# Is there any way to improve performance of loading images from assets?

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, imageview

I have a ListView with an ImageView in each row.

I have a customAdapter that loads image for each row in getView function.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.listImage = (ImageView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.description = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.description);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);

    }


    ItemDescription des = getItemDescriptionFromFile(items.get(position)
            + "/description.txt");
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    holder.title.setText(des.title);
    holder.description.setText(des.description+(position)%5);

    holder.listImage.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset(items.get(position));
    return row;

}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) {

    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
}
```

But I noticed that the scrolling of the list is not smooth enough.

I googled my problem and this link seems to be the solution:
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

But there are some issues with this code:

```
new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {
private ViewHolder v;

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
    v = params[0];
    return mFakeImageLoader.getImage();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (v.position == position) {
        // If this item hasn't been recycled already, hide the
        // progress and set and show the image
        v.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        v.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        v.icon.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
}.execute(holder);
```

I cannot access to position inside the inner class AsyncTask because position is not final.

Is there any way to access position?

What is the best way to make my list scroll smoothly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHTi28zT7rI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you load all the images from assets into memory before you intialize the adapter and access it from there instead of doing disk I/O on every `getView()` call. This should result in significant improvement.

Comment: You mean I load all the bitmaps in OnCreate method and save them in an array of bitmaps?

Comment: that would be one way to do it. I would suggest doing it in a background thread and initialize the adapter once it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class with static object to act as a cache. This way class object caches assets in first load into memory and in next calls access time to bimtaps using cache will be decreased. Implementing below class you only need to call `Bitmaps.getBitmapFromAsset(context,strName)` instead of your own `getBitmapFromAsset(strName)`. It should be noted that memory used for assets in this way will not be freed up till you leave application since you are using `static` HastTable object.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;


public class Bitmaps {

    private static final Hashtable<String, Bitmap> cache = new Hashtable<String, Bitmap>();

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context c, String strName) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(strName)) {
                InputStream istr = null;
                try {
                    istr = c.getAssets().open(strName);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);

                cache.put(strName, bitmap);
            }
            return cache.get(strName);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think in this way the list won't scroll smooth for the first time.
Am I right?

Comment: Each time you scroll a list view, it calls getView for each visible row. So just scrolling once, all items will be loaded. You can load images in AsynchTask in order to avoid lags and display images after finishig getBitmapFromAsset in doInBackground. If loading images takes too much time, it would be reasonable to load images in system memory using methods provided

Comment: You can display some dummy image in listview if its image is not loaded yet in order to make scrolling of list smoother. This way images will be loaded if necessary and user scrolled to that row.